# How to handle 302 http staus code in curl

Tags: unix, curl

I am trying to access a URL which redirect to a different URL and a file gets downloaded on the browser. Now when i am trying to use curl to access that URL on Linux machine i am getting below response .

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.8</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So is is possible that we can get the same file downloaded in my Linux machine

```
 /home/user/bin/curl -b cookie.txt -k -l 'endpoint'
```

Comment: Use the -L  option, but this is probably already answered somewhere else.

Comment: I have already used that you can see that in my command

Comment: Capital L, in the reference: ``-L, --location (HTTP)  If  the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location ...``